# MySql: Update with Inner Join on two tables hangs

Tags: mysql, performance, join

**Summary:**
I've tried different variations of an update with inner join on two tables in mysql, but all of them take hours for small amounts of data. I thought it should be a basic update, very easy and fast, but it always hangs. Any suggestions how to optimize this to perform better?

**Details:**
In the table student_logins is the ip and time_of_visit of each student who visits. Each IP logs in many times. I want to assign a rank to the IPs by the order in which each IP *first* logged in and add the resulting rank (the ranking number) to each entry in the student_logins table.

**Example:**
If these are sample entries:

10:45 173.99.999.999
10:46 170.99.999.999
10:47 173.99.999.999
10:49 174.99.999.999
10:50 173.99.999.999
10:51 170.99.999.999

Then the table should be updated to show:
1 10:45 173.99.999.999
2 10:46 170.99.999.999
1 10:47 173.99.999.999
1 10:49 174.99.999.999
3 10:50 173.99.999.999
2 10:51 170.99.999.999

**Problem:**
I was able to get the ranking numbers I want with no problem, but my tries to update a table to include that ranking number take hours even with just a few thousand test rows.

I tried directly with one temporary table to contain the rankings, but joining it to the student_logins table in order to update takes hours. I tried creating two temporary tables for each step; the code is below, but it also hangs for hours when I try to UPDATE/INNER JOIN the two temp tables.

```
SET @rank=0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 
(this_rank int(11), ip varchar(16), time_visit datetime, visitor_id int(11))
(SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as this_rank, s.ip, s.time_of_visit as time_visit 
 FROM student_logins s
 order by s.time_of_visit, s.ip);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2 (ip varchar(16), unique_visitor_id int(11))
(SELECT tmp1.ip as ip, MIN(this_rank) as unique_visitor_id    
FROM tmp1 
GROUP BY ip);

UPDATE tmp1
INNER JOIN tmp2 on 
 tmp1.ip = tmp2.ip
SET tmp1.visitor_id = tmp2.unique_visitor_id;
```

In the above code, it runs fast and correctly until the UPDATE statement.. and then hangs for hours.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an index on `tmp2(ip)`.  Actually, this index is probably best:

```
create index idx_tmp2_ip_uvi on tmp2(ip, unique_visitor_id)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! (I think your code should have ip in the parentheses, not id, but just a typo I think). On the main table it takes 0.4 seconds now... thanks!! :)